# Vertically aligned text in a variably-sized LI element with 100% height of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I'm having a bit of a hard time positioning text correctly in an `<li>`.

I am using a sass version of bootstrap 3 and am trying to design something similar in appearance to the 'More' and 'Trash' buttons in iOS mail.

Here is a link to the current result. Notice the list item with red background and only one line of text has a shorter height, so the button text is positioned too low.

http://jsfiddle.net/kvseelbach/MRa4C/8/

I would like to have variable height rows instead of forcing all the list items to fit two lines of text. How can I improve this design and fix the height issue?

The core CSS for the li action items:

```
.item-actions li {
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 91px;
    /* 107px height - 16px font size  */
}
li.mailbox-item {
    max-height: 107px;
}
```

Comment: Unless you use percentages and you wouldn't have a good result then, I don't think that is possible with just CSS, I would use javascript to compute the needed values and override them.

Comment: I've considered that, it's an angular app and I should be able to detect the height of the <li> when I am truncating the text in the message body... it's not shown in the example, but I think the directive could be made to add a specific class to the action item buttons when it does the clamp. I'll try that if nothing else works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it if you are willing to tweak the HTML:

**HTML:**

```
<div  class="item-actions-wrap">
    <ul class="item-actions">
      <li class="archive">Archive</li>
      <li class="view"><a href="#">View</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item-actions-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
}
ul.item-actions {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    display: table;
}
.item-actions li {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

see demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/c56zF/

Wrap your list item in a block level `div` that is absolutely positioned.

Within the `div`, apply `display: table` to the `ul` and then `display: table-cell` to the
list items.  For the `li`, apply `vertical-align: middle` and you get nice vertical centering.

Note: You do have another problem because the absolutely positioned block is hiding some
of the content from the adjacent element.  You need to allow some space for the absolute
block.

Comment: Thanks! That worked very well. And I'm glad you gave me a good demo of `display: table-cell;`. I read about that property on learnlayout.com recently but haven't figured out how to put everything together. Do you mean the buttons? They are not static in the actual webapp. They toggle show/hide in javascript.

Comment: If your bottoms are toggled, then please ignore my comment. I thought your layout was static instead of interactive.